# Creating a default command prompt directory

Tags: command-prompt

I was just curious if it would be possible to create a default directory in command prompt. I'm running my java programs in cmd and when I open it during a new session I always want it to start off in a specific folder so i don't have to manually navigate to the folder using the cd process.

I think i'm making this process more difficult than it needs to be. Can anyone tell me how i can create a batch file shortcut to the directory instead ?

Comment: execute `start /d c:\the\path\you\want cmd.exe`

Comment: @MarcB Ok, but it gives me an error when i type in my name...due to a space in my name Amber Roxanna, it says Roxanna not found.

Comment: you can use `"` on paths that have spaces. e.g .`"C:\Program Files\..."`.

Comment: @MarcB ok I got that part to work, only last issues is that anything i type after my name is not included in the cmd. c:\Users\Amber Roxanna\stopsatthispoint

Comment: @MarcB to clarify, it's all included after executing the command you gave me but one i close it and re-open cmd only the part up to my name is shown

Comment: that's normal. when you manually run cmd from the start menu, it starts at c:\users\username. if you want it to start somewhere else, you'll have to put the above command into a shortcut and run the shortcut instead.

Comment: @MarcB Ok, thank you. Defeats the purpose of what I wanted to do which is open up to a specific folder every time i run cmd. This has at least saved me 2 steps. This is what I want the cmd to always display c:\Users\Amber Roxanna\introcs\hello but i'm only having luck with c:\Users\Amber Roxanna i guess this is as far as i can go ?

Comment: you could also assign your desired path to a variable with setx and use that variable to move to that location. cd %variable%

Comment: @edi_allen do you mean SETX MYPATH %PATH% ?

Comment: @AmberRoxanna: setx hello "c:\Users\Amber Roxanna\introcs\hello". then just do cd %hello%, this will be equivalent to cd c:\Users\Amber Roxanna\introcs\hello.

Comment: @edi_allen one word: BOSS :)

Comment: @AmberRoxanna: I'm going to post it as an answer.

Comment: another way to start CMD with a different path is simply copy the CMD.exe from %SYSTEMROOT% to the desired folder, then you can create a batch file to start that CMD prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your long pathname in a **variable** and use that variable as an argument to cd.

```
C:\> setx go "C:\Users\Edisson\Documents\sampdb\Support"
#restart session
C:\> cd %go% 
C:\Users\Edisson\Documents\sampdb\Support\>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to easily run your Java programs without always having to type
`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk#.#.###\bin\java.exe" ...`
I thought the same and so did it. You can add the folder above (your jdk) to be included in cmd default paths by including it in the %PATH% system/environment variable, this is done in Windows 7 by opening Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables, under System variables choose the one called PATH and edit, add a semicolon to declare the end of the last path and copy the path of your JRE/JDK in to look something like:
`...;...;...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\`
To test it open up Command Prompt and type `set` to view all declared variables, PATH should now include your java path, meaning you can simply mention `java` or `javac` now.

Comment: Not exactly I wanted. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I can already use the java and javac commands. My problem is that I don't want to always navigate to the folder containing my java programs. I want to start up command prompt with the path to the folder already present.

Comment: Create a shotcut to Command Prompt, under the shortcut's propeties set the "Start In" folder to your project's, this has the equivalent effect of using the cd command - but it's done for you.